# Unable to start Apache Tomcat v9.0 server for Spring Boot Rest Api

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, tomcat8, java-ee-8

I am new to Spring Boot. I am building a rest API with spring boot 2.2, hibernate 5 and MySQL on a java 1.8 compiler. When I run my spring boot rest API application on my apache tomcat v8.0 server, the server starts and the application runs and displays my index page. After building (clean install) my application and try to run it on the server, the server refuses to start with error "Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start.". Please, what could be the cause of this?

Here's the full error:

```
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.27
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 7 2019 09:57:22 UTC
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.27.0
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_171-b11
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE: C:\Users\Harry\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0 
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software 
Foundation\Tomcat 9.0 
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
log INFO: Command line argument: Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Harry\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.ser 
ver.core\tmp0
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache 
Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
log INFO: Command line argument: Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Harry\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed
 Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
 Dec 12, 2019 8:42:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
 INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: 
 [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/ProgramFiles/Java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/ProgramFiles/Java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/../jre/bin;C:/ProgramFiles/Java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CommonFiles\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft VSCode\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\penSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Harry\workspace\apache-maven-3.6.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VSCode\bin;C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Harry\appData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts;;C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse;;.]
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:13 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8083"]
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:13 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8012"]
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Server initialization in [1,929] milliseconds
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
Dec 12, 2019 8:42:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath

 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
'  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)
 2019-12-12 08:42:30.969  INFO 22232 --- [main] c.a.e.SpringBootApplications: Starting SpringBootApplications v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on Harry with PID 22232(C:\Users\Harry\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0 wtpwebapps\ecclesiamainframe\WEB-INF\classes started by Harry in C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\eclipse) 2019-12-12 08:42:30.993  INFO 22232 --- [main] c.a.e.SpringBootApplications    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default 2019-12-12 08:42:35.300  INFO 22232 --- [main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPArepositories in DEFAULT mode.
 2019-12-12 08:42:35.720  INFO 22232 ---[main].s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 349ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
 2019-12-12 08:42:37.814  INFO 22232 --- [main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
 2019-12-12 08:42:38.008  INFO 22232 --- [main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/ecclesiamainframe]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
 2019-12-12 08:42:38.008  INFO 22232 --- [main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6786 ms
 2019-12-12 08:42:38.622  WARN 22232 --- [main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
 2019-12-12 08:42:38.664  INFO 22232 --- [main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
 2019-12-12 08:42:38.682 ERROR 22232 --- [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

 Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


 Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Here's my pox.xml:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.app</groupId>
 <artifactId>ecclesiamainframe</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>ecclesiamainframe Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>

 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>

<!-- exclude tomcat jdbc connection pool, use HikariCP -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
 <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- exclude tomcat-jdbc , spring boot will use use HikariCP automatically -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency> -->

 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  <scope>providedRuntime</scope>
</dependency>
<!--  
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
-->
 <dependency> 
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId> 
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>  
     <scope>provided</scope> 
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.0</version>
 </dependency> 

</dependencies>

<build>
 <plugins>
     <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
  <finalName>ecclesiamainframe</finalName>
 </build>

</project>
```

Here's my Application.properties

```
        #Database connection Properties
        spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecclesia_mainframe_db
        #?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=yes

        #database credential
        spring.datasource.username = devteam
        spring.datasource.password = softmysql2019
        server.port=8090
        spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

        #The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
        spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

        #spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=200000
        #spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=3000

        #Turn Statistics on and log SQL stmts

        spring.jpa.show-sql=true
        spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

        #If want to see very extensive logging
        spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
        logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
        logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=debug

        #Schema will be created using schema.sql and data.sql files
        #spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none


        #Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
        spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I have tried loads of solutions on stack and error still persists.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide some code sample, and the complete exception raised so we can help you? Thank you.

Comment: I have added the full error response

Answer (score 0):

Could **Clean** your Tomcat Server.
In Eclipse Right Click on your server and click clean to clear previous project.
OR else
in Eclipse
**Delete** Server and add another instance of tomcat.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr67k.png)

Answer (score 0):

The minimum version of tomcat supported by Spring boot 2.2 is tomcat 8.5 so I think that's why you have errors with tomcat 8.0.

Source : https://www.baeldung.com/new-spring-boot-2

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

by

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```